# Java cast: Which is better -- the imperative or programmatic way?

Tags: java, casting

I have seen that there are two ways to cast an object in Java:

```
List<Object> l = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Object> first = (ArrayList<Object>) l;
ArrayList<Object> second = ArrayList.class.cast(l);
```

Which is better and why?

Comment: No, I took the first two class I had in mind...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The better method is the most readable. If you already know what class to do the type cast, use `(ClassToUpcast) object`. If you don't know the class **but** you have the `Class<ClassToUpcast> clazz` object, then use `clazz.cast(object)`.

Comment: Can, the same motivation, be applied also for others method like `isAssignableFrom` instead of `instanceof`?

Comment: @rascio yes. If you're using reflection, then this is the way to go since you don't know the real types which you will use.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Object> second = ArrayList.class.cast(l);` should give you a compiler warning as this reflective operation is not able to check the type parameter of the list.

`ArrayList<Object> first = (ArrayList<Object>) l;` on the other hand is a non-reflective operation for which the compiler can prove that the type parameters of List and ArrayList are the same and therefore that this is a safe operation.

So it should be clear which one is to prefer.